# Open my Electron App from a webpage using a registered protocol

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, protocols

I am using app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("bithop"); but when I navigate to bithop:// in my browser, I just get the default electron app. (Where it says "To run a local app...")

[image]

This is not packaged as a .asar app. The documentation on this seems to be very unclear.

```
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("bithop");
```

(This is the last line of app.js)

When I go to bithop:// from a web browser, it should open my electron app.

[image]

This is the entire script:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let window;

function createWindow() {
  window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false
  });
  window.loadFile('pages/index.html');
  //window.openDevTools();
  window.on('closed', function () {
    window = null;
  });
};

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', app.quit)

//Register Protocol
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("bithop");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to download the electron binaries, and put my app inside it, instead of installing as an npm module. I used https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager, which was really simple.